# Only repo is getting cloned,not executing code

Tags: jenkins

When I run my code from git repo,using jenkins tool,actual code is not getting executed but only remote repository is getting cloned into my system.

Is it the expected behaviour,if it is please help me how can I execute the actual code?

According to my knowledge code should be executed,why its not happening,please help me in this regard.

Comment: How is your Jenkins job configured?

Comment: @StephenKing,its a freestyle project with build periodically used

Comment: Okay, and what commands did you enter to be executed. None, I guess? That's why it does nothing...

Comment: Just as @StephenKing said, that's the expected behaviour. You need to add build steps that actualy perform what you want on repository.